# Get "The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread" error while getting content from Clipboard

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, clipboard, c++-winrt

**Aim**: Get content from the clipboard using C++/WinRT APIs.

**Problem**:

Since I'm just testing this API, I tried to code a simple console app with the blocking `get()` method on Clipboard's async text getter. However, I'm getting the *"The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread"* error when debugging. I also tried to init apartments as single threaded apartment (STA), but I guess it's not allowed because another assertion error (`!is_sta()`) is thrown. Now I'm just wondering why this error is thrown when calling get and how to retrieve the content from clipboard in my console app. (I saw some examples (mostly GUI apps) are using coroutines which I'm not familiar with though.)

**Code**:

```cpp
using namespace winrt::Windows::ApplicationModel::DataTransfer;

int main()
{
    init_apartment();

    hstring text{ Clipboard::GetContent().GetTextAsync().get() };
    std::wcout << text.c_str() << std::endl;
}
```

**Error message**:

```
Exception thrown at 0x7659ACC2 (KernelBase.dll) in test-clipboard.exe: WinRT originate error - 0x8001010E : 'The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread.'.
'test-clipboard.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\bcrypt.dll'. 
Exception thrown at 0x7659ACC2 in test-clipboard.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: winrt::hresult_wrong_thread at memory location 0x010FF818.
Unhandled exception at 0x7659ACC2 in test-clipboard.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: winrt::hresult_wrong_thread at memory location 0x010FF818.
```

Sincerely appreciate your help. Thanks.

Comment: As a new user, please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Concerning your question, I remove the keywords from the title (that's what tags are for). Also, maybe that error message you get was actually in the clipboard? With just your interpretation, it's impossible to tell, so describe what you did and where you saw that message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The WinRT clipboard APIs can only be called from a UI thread with a CoreWindow. See notes [In the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer.Clipboard?view=winrt-18362). You can just use the regular Win32 clipboard APIs in your console app.

Comment: I believe the documentation is a bit inaccurate. There is no strict requirement for a `CoreWindow` instance. A thread with a [DispatcherQueue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.dispatcherqueue) should be sufficient (although I haven't had time to verify this).

Comment: There are checks for "foreground window" for AppContainer... Question is whether it bypasses the CoreWindow before it realizes this is full trust.